# RequiredFieldValidator not correct working when i use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, requiredfieldvalidator

When I fired btn event. after refresh page and RegisterStartupScript my asp.net validators not working corectly

```
protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NotifyShow("example");
}
public void NotifyShow(string msg)
{
    string myScript = string.Format("ShowMessages('{0}','{1}');", msg, "type");
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    str.Append(myScript);

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),
        "AlertJS", str.ToString(), true);
}
```

this HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="main">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtb1" ValidationGroup="g1" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtb1" Text="not  valid" ValidationGroup="g1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSumbit" ValidationGroup="g1" OnClick="btnSumbit_Click"/>
</div>
</form>
```

this javascript

```
function ShowMessages(messageText, type) {
var images = "";

document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML + "<div id='MessagePopUp' class='" + type + "' title='Error message'>" +"" +"<p id='MessageText' style='direction: rtl; margin: 0px auto; padding: 5px;'>" + messageText + "</p>" +"</div>";

var popUp = document.getElementById("MessagePopUp");

$("#MessagePopUp").show("slide", 1000, function () {
    $("#MessagePopUp").hide("slide", 2000, function () {

        document.getElementById("main").removeChild(popUp);
    });
}).delay(4000);}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on "not working correctly"?

Comment: when my fields is not valid and fired again btn, validators text not visible!

Comment: Could you paste the HTML code as well? Possibly the ShowMessages() function is not defined yet when it is being called.

Comment: Let's start with trying to alert('test') with RegisterStartupScript(), if this works, the problem is in js function ShowMessages() you should inspect the elements using firebug or any tools to inspect elements and errors within the browser. If alert() doesn't work, the problem is within RegisterStartupScript(). Let us know the result. :)

Comment: i do that. alert working without any problem and show validation text. in result my js code have a wrong solution. any one can help me to resolve this problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve that when changing my js code to :

```js
function ShowMessages(messageText, type) {
    var html='<div id="MessagePopUp" class="' + type + '" title="Error message"><p id="MessageText" style="direction: rtl; margin: 0px auto; padding: 5px;">' + messageText + '</p></div>';
    addElement('main', 'div', 'tempElement', html);
   var popUp = $("#MessagePopUp");

    $("#MessagePopUp").show("slide", 1000, function () {
        $("#MessagePopUp").hide("slide", 2000, function () {
            removeElement('tempElement');
        });
    }).delay(4000);
}
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
    // Adds an element to the document
    var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
    var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
    newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
    newElement.innerHTML = html;
    p.appendChild(newElement);
}
function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```